# Qt: what are the differences between QtScript and Javascript in Webkit

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, webkit, qtscript

I am familiar with web development so I know exactly what Javascript can do in webkit. If I want to employ the scripting feature in my apps, I think there are two ways:

1. Employ qtwebkit and open a hidden webpage running my own Javascript scripts.
2. Using qtscript.

Right now I want most of my app logic are implemented with scripts but I am wondering what are differences between them and how to choose under different circumstances, javascript in webkit or qtscript?

Sorry if this question is not that professional. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the following

> Qt 4.3 and later provides support for
>   application scripting with ECMAScript.

in [Making Applications Scriptable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/topics-scripting.html) section in Qt docs one comes to conclusion that QtScript is just a name of Java Script ([ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) is the name of the Java Script's official specification) implementation in Qt.

Additionaly in [QtScript in 4.6](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2009/11/23/qtscript-in-46/) article on Qt Labs page we find the following information

> (...) Qt 4.6′s QtScript implementation is
>   based on WebKit’s JavaScript engine,
>   JavaScriptCore (...)

This gives you a very strong guarantee that QtScript's behaviour will match the one you know from WebKit's implementation.

If you just want to add scripting to your application and you don't need anything related to WebKit then it's enough to use QScriptEngine class which [*provides an environment for evaluating Qt Script code*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscriptengine.html#details).